# how can I prevent a user to type 0 as the first character in a text input using vanilla javascript?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have this html block:

```
<div class="form-group flex-auto" >
                <input maxlength="2" class="form-control format__itemForm" type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.codigoPaisTelefono"   prevent-keys="{{ $ctrl.caracteresExcluidos }}"
                required oninput="this.value== 0? this.value == '' :void(0)"
                > 
            </div>
```

I need to prevent users to type 0 as the first character, I tried oninput method above, but didn't work.

Any clue?

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:angularjs] if you are asking for a vanilla solution? Did you mean AngularJS or Vanilla?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*prevent*"? What if a user enters zero in a second position and the deletes the first character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```js
function validate(element){
  var val = element.value;
  if(val.charAt(0)=='0'){
    element.value=val.substring(1, val.length);
  }
}
```

```html
<input oninput="validate(this)">
```